# Choose-Command popup in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, api, command

I would like to ask if there exists some functionality in eclipse where it's possible to choose all available commands, instead of having to remember all the shortcuts.

Something like the command palette in sublime text 2. Where you by pressing ctrl+shift+p (windows/linux) get an input popup box where all availble commands can be choosen.

Does such a feature exists for eclipse, or should I develop it by myself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find anything, so I have started on developing my own plugin.

Answer (score 8):

I just bumped into this feature by accident but looking up to see if I figure how to get to it. it looked like it popped up when I started typing after having launched eclipse without focusing on any particular view... more to come as soon as I find out for sure.

EDIT: Apparently when you first launch Eclipse the focus is on the "Quick Action" search box on the top right of the tool bar and that's where you can start typing command names for it to list and let you pick in good Sublime Text style. Not sure how to shortcut into the box other than clicking it, but apparently there's the feature.

EDIT#2: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseShortcuts/article.html#shortcuts_overview describes Ctrl+3 as being the shortcut to get there, on the Mac it translates to Cmd+3.